# How to neatly paste lists as columns?

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting

I have two lists of words:

```
$ head -n 15 words.txt > list1
$ tail -n 15 words.txt > list2
```

I paste them together into columns:

```
$ paste list1 list2
```

The result is this, with tabs between the columns:

```
2       Zwiebel
1080    zwieselite
&c      Zwingle
10-point        Zwingli
10th    Zwinglian
11-point        Zwinglianism
12-point        Zwinglianist
16-point        zwitter
18-point        zwitterion
1st     zwitterionic
2,4,5-t Zwolle
2,4-d   Zworykin
20-point        ZZ
2D      zZt
2nd     ZZZ
```

I would like this instead, where there are more tabs between the columns on certain lines:

```
2               Zwiebel
1080            zwieselite
&c              Zwingle
10-point        Zwingli
10th            Zwinglian
11-point        Zwinglianism
12-point        Zwinglianist
16-point        zwitter
18-point        zwitterion
1st             zwitterionic
2,4,5-t         Zwolle
2,4-d           Zworykin
20-point        ZZ
2D              zZt
2nd             ZZZ
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either pipe the result through `column -t`:

```
paste list1 list2 | column -t
```

or use `pr` with the `-m` (merge) option:

```
pr -Tm list1 list2
```

Note that the latter may truncate columns if the output exceeds the current `PAGE_WIDTH` (by default, 72 characters) - if that becomes an issue you may need to increase the page width using `-w`